# what is the difference between coin and token?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, ethereum, solidity

is there any difference between coin, token and protocol?

this is what i understood in ethereum perspective

ethereum  is a protocol ,
    ERC20  is a  token ,
    ETH is a coin

is it correct ?

Comment: You should ask this on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to progamming

Comment: This is related to block chain n crypto currency , I mean this is the base of blockchain and ethereum

Comment: This is a valid question related to blockchain. In fact, all the distributed applications running on blockchain use some sort of tokens and having the understanding of the distinction helps.  Probably, a more relevant site could be https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/, but it deserves to be answered in this forum as well.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any difference between coin, token and protocol?

Yes.

A protocol is a set of rules that define interaction between entities (TCP/IP defines how computers interact, [diplomatic protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(diplomacy)) defines how countries interact)

The difference between coin and token is not that obvious though.

A coin (in this context) is something you can send in the blockchain network. I think it's a value 'natively' supported on this network, like ETH or BTC.

A token is related to ERC20 contracts, and you can think of it as *a portion* of something that the contract gives you (in exchange for ETH for example). In a case of ICO it's a share of future earnings, or the company can promise to replace tokens with real shares after their IPO.

> ethereum is a protocol

No. Ethereum is a network of nodes acting accordingly to [Ethereum Wire Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Wire-Protocol)

> ERC20 is a token

No. It's a standard for contracts which main goal is to distribute tokens (also you can call it an interface). It's used because many exchanges could almost "automatically" add your tokens if you implement it with ERC20. They can do it, because it [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERC20) the method of transfering tokens between addresses:

```
transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success)
```

Among other useful methods.

> ETH is a coin

Yes!

Answer (score 1):

In short we can say Coin is a kind of cryptocurrency which interact with blockchain directly by using set of protocols.

Tokens are basically other kind of cryptocurrency which interact with Blockchain using Smart Contracts.

Ethereum provides concept of Tokens and Smart Contracts which can be written in Solidity only.

Also NEO blockchain launching their Smart Contracts that can be written in Java, .NET, Python and some other languages.